# UFW firewall does not allow any ports (Debian 9)

Tags: linux, debian, ufw

I'm facing a really incredible problem, I don't understand how it is possible elsewhere.

I use `ufw` to manage my ports. I have an FTP server to install on my Linux server. When `ufw` is enable, I can no longer connect to ftp. On the contrary when ufw is deactivated I can access it.

I'm trying to open a port also from before for a socket connection, it doesn't work either.

I tried reinstalling `ufw`, it didn't change anything.

Here is my list of open ports:

```
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
115/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
115/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I have the impression that `ufw` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

In "passive" FTP(*), port 21 is used for control, but for the actual data transfer [the server and client negotiate a port >1024 on the server to which the client connects](https://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html), so you would have to enable that range of ports in UFW.

(*) In traditional FTP it's even worse: the server initiates a connection to the client for the data transfer, but this is rarely used those days.

Comment: The huge range of ports required, the difficulty in encrypting it with TLS (due to people not implementing the standard correctly), and the poor performance compared with HTTP are why FTP has mostly fallen out of fashion.

Comment: The range of ports used for passive FTP is often configurable. And it doesn't need to be much bigger than the expected number of simultaneous connections.

Comment: PS; You should put a `LIMIT` on port 22 and if you enable 115 (SFTP), why 21 (FTP)?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers. No matter how hard I try to open any port (even port 22) when `ufw` is enabled, I have all ports blocked, I never had any problems before